# YES_NO_OPTION JOptionPane continue java code on 'yes'

Tags: java, joptionpane, messagebox

Basically I have a game that brings up the JOptionPane when something happens, I want to be able to return to the game when the user clicks yes. Kind of like an unpause function

Comment: Could you be more precise please? What is your actual goal? Do you want to know the code behind the JOptionPane or do you want to implement a Pane with the Yes_No_Option and don't know how to get this done?

Comment: @DiabolicWords Sorry, I wasn't too sure how to word it, I'd like to know the code behind the JOptionPane

Comment: Okay. Then, I guess, your only chance is to find a good decompiler and have a look on the code in the super class' method. Sorry, this may sound a little unfriendly but it is indeed, as far as I know, the only way to have a look behind the curtains.

Comment: @DiabolicWords I tried this but I couldn't find the code I wanted.
Is there a way of setting the YES_OPTION of a YES_NO_OPTION JOptionPane to continue the java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: When I posted this answer, the question was quite different - read the comments.

Since OpenJDK is open-source (GNU General Public License version 2), you can look at its source code. I usually browse Java source code on grepcode.com. If you install the OracleJDK and select the option to install sources too, you can also find most of the source code in the JDK install directory (src.zip). Just beware, that the license for that might not permit you to reuse this code (it is usually the same) for yourself (but it's certainly a lot better than using a decompiler).

*These links to the specific methods don't work in my favourite browser (Vivaldi, based on Chrome). If you don't wish to have to look for the specific methods yourself, I recommend that you use Firefox.*

Here are the relevant snippets from grepcode.com:

[JOptionPane (constructor)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjavax.swing.Icon%2Cjava.lang.Object[]%2Cjava.lang.Object)) - this is called by every `show...Dialog` method:

```
1830  public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType,
1831                     Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue) {
          ...
1838      setOptionType(optionType);
          ...
1841      updateUI();
1842  }
```

[JOptionPane (updateUI)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.updateUI()):

```
1877  public void updateUI() {
1878      setUI((OptionPaneUI)UIManager.getUI(this));
1879  }
```

Here we see, that the `JOptionPane` requests an `OptionPaneUI` from the `UIManager`. `OptionPaneUI` is an abstract class (that looks more like an interface), so you can't find any code there. Its only subclasses are `BasicOptionPaneUI` or `MultiOptionPaneUI`. Using the debugger, I found that it is `BasicOptionPaneUI` for a `showConfirmDialog`. Afterwards, the result is passed into the `setUI` method inherited from `JComponent`. Other than some basic field checking, it calls the [ui.installUI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicOptionPaneUI.java#BasicOptionPaneUI.installUI(javax.swing.JComponent)) method:

```
137   public void installUI(JComponent c) {
138       optionPane = (JOptionPane)c;
139       installDefaults();
140       optionPane.setLayout(createLayoutManager());
141       installComponents();
142       installListeners();
143       installKeyboardActions();
144   }
```

Let's look at [installComponents](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicOptionPaneUI.java#BasicOptionPaneUI.installComponents()) next:

```
171   protected void More ...installComponents() {
172       optionPane.add(createMessageArea());
173 
174       Container separator = createSeparator();
175       if (separator != null) {
176           optionPane.add(separator);
177       }
178       optionPane.add(createButtonArea());
179       optionPane.applyComponentOrientation(optionPane.getComponentOrientation());
180   }
```

[createButtonArea](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicOptionPaneUI.java#BasicOptionPaneUI.createButtonArea()) sound quite promising:

```
613   protected Container createButtonArea() {
614       JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
          ...
630       addButtonComponents(bottom, getButtons(), getInitialValueIndex());
631       return bottom;
632   }
```

This method now calls [addButtonComponents](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicOptionPaneUI.java#BasicOptionPaneUI.addButtonComponents(java.awt.Container%2Cjava.lang.Object[]%2Cint)). This method is too long to copy here, but, in short, it gets the locale-specific strings for the buttons and adds them as [JButton](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JButton.java#JButton)s. It then gives each of them a [ButtonActionListener](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicOptionPaneUI.java#BasicOptionPaneUI.ButtonActionListener).

Comment: That's great to know but doesn't really answer my question of how do I return play to the game?

Comment: @Eishknaar Well, you pretty much edited your question to the point of only keeping 1 word (excluding articles and pronouns). I believe this answer is valid for your original question, while I agree it has nothing to do with your edit.

Comment: @Eishknaar Regarding this new unpause question, you just have to read the documentation. JOptionPane is by default a modal dialogue. This means, that a call to show the JOptionPane will block, until the JOptionPane is closed, at which point the show method returns and your code continues. This isn't affected in any way by JOptionPane's input type. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#create

Comment: Really helpful! Still haven't managed to find the exact solution yet, but definitely closer now :)

Comment: After getting the example from your link, all I needed was a setter for the frame. Works perfectly now, thank you so much!